# Google Sheets formula to calculate bills remaining to be paid based on bills already paid

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets doc that I use to track my monthly bills. In one column I have the amount that is owed each payday. As a bill gets paid, in another column next to it I place an X, this was I know it has been paid.

I want a formula that will calculate the sum of all bills left to be paid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Column A   "Bill" 5 7 11
column B   "Paid" x    x
```

in the total cell

```
=sumif(B2:B4,"X",A2:A4)
```

[image: Sumif syntax]

Comment: Awesome Thanks! I thought it might be a SUMIF formula, but couldn't figure it out!